# Create n numbers of for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, random

I want to run a code with n number of for loops. For example, I have this code:

```
import random

random_numbers= ["1","5"]
# 2 objects
# the program will create two for loops, with n times until it gets the correct object.

a = random_numbers[0]
b = random_numbers[1]

for x in range(): 
    a1 = random.randint(1,9)
    if  a1==a:
        print(a1)
        break
for x in range (): 
    a2 = random.randint(1,9)
    if  a2==b:
        print(a2)
        break
```

For example, I have these random objects ["1", "5"}, this means that I have two objects, the program will create two for loops, each for loop will generate a random number from 1-9. If the first for loop is equal to the first vector ("1") it will be printed, if not, it will generate again until it is matched to "1". Then,  the second loop will also generate a random number, the same rule in the first loop. But this time the generated number of the 2nd loop must equal to second vector ("5"). So the final output must be:

Output: ["1", "5"]

I'm looking for general code that creates n number of for loops, it is possible to have more than two random numbers (Ex: Input: 1,5,7,2 Output: 1,5,7,2)

Comment: range expects to get at least one argument, but you haven't given any argument to this function. Is that ok for you?

Comment: What's the point? Just print `random_numbers`.

Comment: A random integer will never equal a string like `'5'`

Comment: The point is, what if I generate a random number? This program is for the decoding of passwords. Tho, my main question is how to generate n numbers  offor loops, which can be used in different applications of generating a random number with different conditions.

Comment: @JohnColeman, this is an example. You may edit the random_numbers to string.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Perhaps `itertools` could help.

Comment: You already know about ``for .. in range``, which repeats a code block a specific number of times. What is stopping you from putting *a for loop* into it to repeat the for loop a specific number of times?

Comment: Can you please [edit] the code so that it is at least sensible? The ``random_numbers`` aren't numbers, so they will *never* match a ``random.randint``; the ``for x in range():`` miss the count of iterations. See the [mre] help page for what requirements code should satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to understand the logic behind your question because you can directly print `random_numbers`. Here's a way you can check the elements in `random_numbers`. It'll run `n` times where `n` is the no.of elements in the list. It runs till the random int is equal to the item in `random_numbers`. I don't know why you require `n` for loops when you can run for loops `n` times.

```
import random

random_numbers = [1, 5]
for i in random_numbers: 
    while True:
        if random.randint(1,9) == i:
            print(f"Found:{i}")
            break
```

Output:

```
Found:1
Found:5
```

Thanks @Kelly for the comment. But how does it help in improving the efficiency?